# Display Wordpress parent Category with their child category

Tags: wordpress

I want to display only those the parent category which have some child category with their child category without using `child_of=`

I was trying to display but i am only able to get the list of child category not their parent category name.

```
<?php

$querystr = "SELECT wp_terms.name, wp_terms.term_id, wp_terms.name FROM wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy WHERE wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.parent !=0 ";
$cat_child = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
var_dump($cat_child);
foreach ($cat_child as $category) {
         echo $category->name. ' , ';
      }
  ?>
```

Help me..
Thanks

Comment: So you want to show just the *parent* of a given category?

Comment: yes i want to display the parent category of that child category

Answer (score 2):

Done by doing this

```
<?php

                            $querystr = "SELECT wp_terms.name, wp_terms.term_id, wp_terms.name FROM wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy WHERE wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.parent !=0 ";
                            $cat_child = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
                            var_dump($cat_child);
                            echo '<ul>';
                            foreach ($cat_child as $category) {
                                 $cat_id = intval($category->term_id);
                                 echo '<li>';
                                    echo get_category_parents($cat_id , TRUE , ' <br/> ');
                                 echo '</li>';
                            }
                            echo '</ul>';
                     ?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use "child_of" argument then your problem can be solved by using two loops one for [displaying parent categories](http://www.upaae.com/how-to-display-only-wordpress-parent-categories/) and other for [displaying its direct child categories.](http://www.upaae.com/display-child-categories-of-selected-parent-category-in-wordpress-category-page/)

```
  // get_categories() function will return all the categories
        $upaae_categories = get_categories( array(
         'orderby' => 'name',
         'order' => 'ASC'
        ) );

        foreach( $upaae_categories as $single_cat ) {
         if($single_cat->parent < 1) // Display if parent category and exclude child categories
         {
    echo 'Parent: '.$single_cat->name;
    // now get all the child categories
    $child_categories=get_categories(
        array( 'parent' => $single_cat->term_id )
    );
    if(sizeof($child_categories)>0){ /* this is just for ensuring that this parent category do have child categories otherwise a category cannot be a parent if does not have any child categories*/
    echo '###childs###</br>'
    foreach ($child_categories as $child) {

        echo $child->name.'</br>';
    }// end of loop displaying child categories
    } //end of if parent have child categories

         }
        }
```